# Rails 3: method delegations with nil relationships

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Given the following (vastly simplified) objects:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :characters
end

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  delegate :name, :to => :player, :prefix => :player
end
```

I need to display the player name in several views.  But it's totally valid (and expected) that the Player might be nil.

I've currently handled this via a method as follows:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player

  def player_name
    player ? player.name : 'Unknown'
  end
end
```

I don't like this for several reasons.  Is there a nicer way of doing this?

Comment: delegate has :allow_nil => true  http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/Module/delegate

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I discovered that after posting the question and have started using it.  I was hoping there was a way of defining a 'default' value, but I think having it be 'empty' in my views is almost as good/informative and does clean up my models.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're dealing with mostly view-related code, you might find using an "or" in conjunction with `allow_nil: true` on the `delegate` call feels natural:

```
Name: <%= @character.player_name || 'Unknown' %>
```

Another interesting pattern you may consider is the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern); using this pattern, you describe "default" behavior using an object that represents a "null" or missing value for that object. For example, (pseudocode-ish):

```
class NullPlayer
  def name
    'Unknown'
  end
end

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player

  delegate :name, to: :player, prefix: :player, allow_nil: true

  # overwrite default player accessor
  def player
    super || NullPlayer.new
  end
end
```

This pattern is a bit more heavy handed, but you may find it appropriate depending on your application.

Finally, [the code for `delegate` isn't too complicated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e4ec944eacbb58ed682614cb3271dc58e4d71b52/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb). You *could* write your own version of this method that takes a `default` argument to use in the case of `nil`:

```
delegate :name, to: :player, prefix: :player, default: 'Unknown'
```

Comment: Thanks.. It was really helpful.

Comment: One important part to note is the `prefix: :player`, i'm in a kind of hell right now dealing with my own mistake of not adding that to delegated methods in a large code base and i REALLY wish i'd added it.